# facing problems modifying object properties

Tags: javascript, angular

due to some confusion I am not able to manipulate an existing object based on another object while performing inside for-loop. I am using Angular for my project and here is code:

**object A**

```
object_a = {

  "status1": {
      "volume": 100,
      "processed": 23,
      "progress": 77
  },

  "status2": {
      "volume": 100,
      "processed": 23,
      "progress": 77
  },

  "status3": {
      "volume": 100,
      "processed": 23,
      "progress": 77
  },

  "status4": {
      "volume": 50,
      "processed": 2,
      "progress": 3
  }

}
```

**object B**

```
object_b = {

  "status1": {
      "volume": 300,
      "processed": 200,
      "progress": 100
  },

}
```

This is how I am using it:

```
    let count = 0;
    for(const keyLevel1 in this.object_a){
          let valueLevel1 = this.object_a[keyLevel1];
          let valueObj = {};
          isIncorrect[keyLevel1] = false;
          for(const keyLevel2 in valueLevel1){
            let valueLevel2 = this.object_a[keyLevel1][keyLevel2];
            if(Math.sign(valueLevel2) == -1 || valueLevel2 == "NA"){
              isIncorrect[keyLevel1] = true;
              if(this.object_b !== undefined && 
    Object.keys(this.object_b).length > 0){
    // here i am trying to overwrite                
    objAfterCopy = Object.assign({}, this.object_a, this.object_b[keyLevel1]);
              }
            }else{
              valueObj[keyLevel2] = valueLevel2;
              this.object_b[keyLevel1] = valueObj;
            }
          }
          if (!isIncorrect[keyLevel1]){
            this.object_a[keyLevel1] = state[Object.keys(state)[count]];
            count++;
          }
        }
```

What the above code does is that it checks for any negative number or "NA" assigned in the number fields and if that is the case then it will assign the correct flag to true. If the number is valid number then it will try to copy that number from object_b and overwrite it to object_a in it's correct property. I hope this explanation helps.

I want to replace `status1` property of object_a with object_b's.

**What I want?**

So final output of **object_a** should be:

```
object_a = {

  "status1": {
      "volume": 300,
      "processed": 200,
      "progress": 100
  },

  "status2": {
      "volume": 100,
      "processed": 23,
      "progress": 77
  },

  "status3": {
      "volume": 100,
      "processed": 23,
      "progress": 77
  },

  "status4": {
      "volume": 50,
      "processed": 2,
      "progress": 3
  }

}
```

**What I tried**

`Object.assign({}, this.object_a["status1"], this.object_b["status1"]);`

I tried doing like this but then it replaces entire `object_a` with `status1` values, removing all other properties.

I also tried

`this.object_a["status1"] = this.object_b["status1"]`

but then it throws `Cannot assign to read only property`

Can somebody please tell me why its not working? I just couldn't get this to work.

Comment: Why are you using enhanced quotes?

Comment: i am not using these quotes in code. its just that i copied it for illustration from word. I will format my question.

Comment: `Cannot assign to read only property` There's some code that's missing.

Comment: I run your code in the console and the code is valid. 

Maybe you are not telling us something. `this.object_a["status1"] = this.object_b["status1"]` is working as expected.

Comment: @HereticMonkey and StPaulis I have updated my question. Please recheck, you shall find all details how i have used these objects in for loop. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Dhruvify check my answer below, maybe it will help you out, it is simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
object_a = {...object_a, status1: object_b.status1}
```

Of course both of them has to be at least `const` type so:

`const object_a` and `const object_b`

or even simpler:

```
object_a.status1 = {...object_b.status1}
```

Comment: `object_a.status1 = {...object_b.status1}` i used this and it did worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
const obj = {...object_a,...object_b};
object_a = obj;
console.log(object_a);
```

Here left Object will overlap the existing Property if found if not then will join it as property

Comment: hi toxy. joining is really not good idea in my case it might give some additional numbers which i dont need. hence i had accepted the above answer as it works just how i wanted. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just overthinking it. I've never used the `Object.assign` method, just directly re-assigned.

```js
const object_a = {

  "status1": {
      "volume": 100,
      "processed": 23,
      "progress": 77
  },

  "status2": {
      "volume": 100,
      "processed": 23,
      "progress": 77
  },

  "status3": {
      "volume": 100,
      "processed": 23,
      "progress": 77
  },

  "status4": {
      "volume": 50,
      "processed": 2,
      "progress": 3
  }

}

let object_b = {

  "status1": {
  "volume": 300,
  "processed": 200,
  "progress": 100
  },

}

object_a.status1 = object_b.status1;

console.log(object_a)
```

Comment: i had tried before using simple equals(=) but resulted in read only property cannot be modified error

Comment: Ah understood. In the future, it is helpful to upload the minimal amount of code that allows the community to reproduce the issue. Glad you got it resolved though.